# Dns.GetHostEntry not working with 'http://'

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, dns

If I try to resolve a website's IP with a url that includes `http://` (at the beginning of the url) or `/` (at the end of the url), it won't work. How can I parse any url given by the user to a url that works with `Dns.GetHostEntry` method?

Comment: Since `GetHostEntry` requires host, this search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+get+host+out+of+url could help you find more answers if duplicate I pick is not enough. If you feel that duplicate does not cover whole problem - make sure to update question with such information so it can be re-opened.